# Laravel error on hosting You don't have permission to access /storage/product_images/14/ZfUI13V1bdrsTtqFR4zdsGHgc3oSRbtOUiD3lwJG.jpeg on this server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, веб-сервер, hosting

Вручную создал symlink в папке public_html которая ссылается к папке storage/app/public ,
изменил все permissions на 777(знаю что небезопасно) ответ сервера все тотже,

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access
>   /storage/product_images/14/19/20/ZfUI13V1bdrsTtqFR4zdsGHgc3oSRbtOUiD3lwJG.jpeg
>   on this server.

у меня все изображения находятся в storage публик диске, и все они не показываются браузером.

Что делать ?

Answer (score -1):

Нужно чтобы у папки не только права стояли но еще и owner/group были соответствующие тем от которых сервер пытается получить к ней доступ.